# Add to cart freeze website

Tags: magento-1.7, addtocart

I recently discovered that when you click on "add to cart" in a product page, my website freeze (see image below). It add the item in the cart tho. The only way to come back from this is to reload the page. It doesnt do that in the home page (it goes to your shopping cart after adding the product).

Any idea where to look for to solve the problem ?

[image]

Comment: its ajax add to cart, right?

Comment: No it is not @TheMagentoKid

Comment: i have checked and its fine in my side http://www.cafecaps.com . Products are adding to cart on product page

Answer (score 1):

In cafecaps.com homepage, the function add to cart work fine, but on http://www.cafecaps.com/nespresso-capsules.html, the function add to cart launch, in foreground, a loader image, but the image loader doesn't disappear (like in your screenshot).

In my console, with Firefox 38.0.1, I have `TypeError: jQuery.fancybox is undefined`

If I remove the image for recover the web page, the amount of product have been added in cart total amount.

For me, the problem in on js side.

Comment: Could you solve your problem ?